# select if the parent_id is not null

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `models` (
    `id` bigint(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `parent_id` bigint(10) unsigned default 0,
    `date_sent` datetime not null,
    `content` text not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I would like to select the id and the content for a given id,
but if the parent_id is not null, I want the content of the parent, not the child.

I tried this which returns nothing:

```
select id, content from models
    where id = if(parent_id is null, 90, (select parent_id from models where id=90))
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this with a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT m1.id, COALESCE(m2.content,m1.content) as content
FROM models AS m1 LEFT JOIN models AS m2 ON (m2.id = m1.parent_id)
WHERE m1.id = 90;
```

That way if there is a parent it will be joined, and will use the content, but if no parent is found, then it will use that current rows 'content'

Answer (score 1):

A simple LEFT OUTER JOIN, and then use COALESCE to get the first non null field of either the parent content or the normal content.

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.content, a.content)
FROM models a
LEFT OUTER JOIN models b
ON a.parent_id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select id, content from models
 where (parent_id is null and id = 90)
    or id = parent_id
```